# Security question about server root access by wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, security, web

I have a security question. I gave the WordPress admin access to someone for a series of changes. Could he use the shell or any other way to infiltrate the server and access other hosts on server?

Answer (score 0):

> By default, any user that logs in with administrative permissions can access the WordPress plugin and theme editors, and change any theme or plugin file on your site in real-time.

– From https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-files/

That, in theory, leaves your server open to arbitrary code execution. You might consider mitigating this default vulnerability by reviewing trellis's approach of [locking down the root user](https://roots.io/docs/trellis/master/security/), and bedrock's [must-use-plugin-autoloader](https://roots.io/docs/bedrock/master/mu-plugin-autoloader/).

(It's very cool, you define your plugins in a `composer.json` file. Here's the magic sauce of that.)

```
"installer-paths": {
  "web/app/mu-plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-muplugin", "roots/wp-stage-switcher"],
  "web/app/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
  "web/app/themes/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
},
```

That prevents "writing" new code to the theme/plugin folders outside the context of a theme deploy, and so elides the concern of WP admins writing whatever code they like.

(However, if you're assuming a malicious admin, you might be in need of social as much as technologica approaches.)

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**
No

**Long Answer:**
This kind of credentials can be used only from wordpress instance.
He can modify some lines of code by using a custom plugin but he cant go outside the theme folder.
Some plugin can modify the wp-config.php but no more.

By settings you can negate the GUI Plugin installation, so only the server administrator via FTP can install them.

In general, this credentials can modify only file of that wordpress installation because there are present on that Wordpress-DB

None can access via ftp/ssh because he needs user/password and IP of that server.